# Interrupt the execution of a function after X amount of time

Tags: python, selenium

I'm making a selenium script for a website where certain inputs can just load forever. Driver.get does not continue until the page is loaded. I need a way to wrap some of these calls in something that will abort the attempt and move on if it lasts for more than 90 seconds. I looked into using signal(SIGALRM) or interruptingcow, but unfortunately I am on Windows and this doesn't seem to work. Do I have other options?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multiprocessing.Process` :

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def foo():
    for i in range(300):
        print "tick"
        time.sleep(1)

# start fonction as a process
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo) p.start()

# wait 10 seconds or until process is finished
p.join(10)

# if process still active
if p.is_alive():
    # Terminate
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```